# Formatting for failure output of BOOST_CHECK_CLOSE?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

I am adding tests to legacy code using the boost test framework.

One such test might be

```
double expectedPrice = /*...local computation*/
BOOST_CHECK_CLOSE(expectedPrice, object->price, ACCURACY_THRESHOLD);
```

Where expectedPrice is a double computed locally and the object is retrieved from the system under test.

```
error in "MyTest": difference{0.21097%} between expectedPrice{4.7300000000000004} and object->price{4.7400000000000002} exceeds 1.0000000000000001e-05%
```

Of course, that is a little hard to read, given all the decimals.  Any way to have the test output formatted better/differently given that I am using naked doubles and not some other type?

Comment: @Martin - they are definitely all doubles.  How will a larger threshold help here?  They are indeed mismatched 4.73 and 4.74 - I'm just looking for more readable output...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is known issue. With known solution. Just a bit hard to implement, though I still hope to do at some point. Meanwhile you are stuck with whatever output your iostream library produces.

Comment: "With known solution" - that I can implement in my code?  Or that is known to boost-people and that the library needs to implement?

Comment: @sdg This is something library can implement. Essentially there is an algorithm which prints floating point values correctly always. It's neither simple, nor very efficient, but it would work for testing framework very well (Unlike the algorithms used by most iostream libs, which are faster, but prone to 0001 or 999999 tails).

Comment: Gennadly more than likely means the de-facto-standard dtoa() algorithm: http://www.netlib.org/fp/dtoa.c

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

cout << setprecision(2)

Comment: Thanks - tried, but did not change.  I presume boost is using something else under the covers...

Comment: From the looks of the code, it's just using operator<<.  If you could figure out which ostream it's using, this should work...